# David Guetta Bang my head/This one's for you PLUCK

Tags: sound-design

The chord pluck from these two david guetta tracks sounds like "rubber" - dont know how to explain.. anyone know how to make it?

I've been looking everywhere for answers

Answer (score 2):

That is a standard sort of pluck....nothing special at all. Sounds like a saw wave for the oscillator.

Then use an ADSR envelope to control a low pass filter. Set the attack, sustain, and release of the envelope all to zero.

Then tweak these values to tweak the sound to your liking
-envelope decay time
-filter cutoff point
-envelope influence of filter (this can be call different things in different synths).

Then when all is said and done, you need to apply the standard spacial effects of reverb, chorus, and possibly mild delay.

I use freeware synth TyrellN6 for all my plucks, and you should too :)

If you are lost as far as my terminology went, spend 10 minutes an watch my intro video...

Comment: i know how to make a standard saw pluck but this is not a standard saw pluck.. it got something else to it like a phaser or something but i cant get it right.. thanks for you answer anyways

Comment: You should have mentioned that you know how to make 99% of the sound. As for the phaser, I think you are perceiving things incorrectly. There is some chorus and reverb. But if you want to emulate things to this fine a detail you will never achieve your goal, because it could be down to a very unique sound of a particular VST.

Comment: I think I hear a metallic layer to it. You might be able to accomplish it with an additional comb filtered layer. I've made metallic-sounding arps with a comb filter combined in serial after an FM oscillator in Zebra2.

Comment: Please define a layer.....